With DDEV add-ons, how can I install a custom command?
I am building a "ddev get" service for https://diffy.website so it is easy to take screenshots from local website.
I would like to provide a command "ddev screenshot" for this.
What would be recommended way of copying the command (I assume in install.yaml file somewhere)? Code is already available in https://github.com/DiffyWebsite/ddev-diffy

Yes, it's super easy to do, and lots of add-ons already do it. See Contributor Training blog about add-on techniques, "Adding project (or global) custom commands":
An add-on can easily add a project custom command. People have made add-ons specifically to add just one project custom command. It seems like a waste, but it's not. It gives your custom command(s) a home, an issue queue, and an upgrade path.
An example of a project that does lots of this is ddev-drupal-contrib, which installs several specialized web custom commands, see install.yaml.
project_files:
  - commands/web/eslint
  - commands/web/expand-composer-json
  - commands/web/nightwatch
  - commands/web/phpcbf
  - commands/web/phpcs
  - commands/web/phpunit
  - commands/web/poser
  - commands/web/stylelint
  - commands/web/symlink-project

